# Print current logging level

Tags: python, logging

Here's a bit of code I'm running under:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("test.logger")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

print("Effective logging level is {}".format(logger.getEffectiveLevel()))
```

And here's the output:

```
Effective logging level is 10
```

How do I print the level instead of the number?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pass the numeric level to [`logging.getLevelName()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.getLevelName):

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.getLevelName(10)
'DEBUG'
```

Does what it says on the tin:

> Returns the textual representation of logging level *lvl*.

For your code that'd be:

```
print("Effective logging level is {}".format(
    logging.getLevelName(logger.getEffectiveLevel())))
```